# What data types can store huge numeric values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an auto-increment column which needs to store very large numbers.

Currently, this column is `BIGINT(20)`, but I would like to know what data types can store larger numbers.

Comment: How big do these numbers get?  Typically values in the billions or trillions (10-16 digits) is more than sufficient for things in the real world.

Comment: my data are insert and drop maybe real time

Comment: Are you using these numbers for anything?

Comment: There are about 31,536,000,000 *milliseconds* in a year.  A big int should suffice for most imaginable purposes.

Comment: Instead of asking what he is using it for, why not just answer his question ?? If he is asking for something just answer it.

Answer (score 2):

DECIMAL(65,0) is the highest native numeric precision available in MySQL 5.6.  A DECIMAL(65,0) will consume 29 bytes (assuming it is not nullable).

See MySQL documentation on:

- [Decimal data type characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)
- [Fixed point types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: how much to store ? 1 and 0 (65 digis) ?

Comment: See updated answer. `DECIMAL(65,0)` will consume 29 bytes.  Why in the world do you need such large numbers?  65 digits is almost enough to account for every particle in the observable universe.